# Trigger "Leave Chat?" by code

Tags: javascript, liveagent

I am working on a custom interface for the live agent widget and was wondering if I could trigger the exit/leave chat by code. Basically, I am removing the X and minimize buttons and want to be able to make some other parts of my UI act as the X button. I looked at the docs, but came up empty. Any suggestions?

Edit: to clarify, I only have access to "embedded_svc" from the web embed snippet SF provides. I also do not want to terminate the chat instantly. My goal is to trigger the exit chat confirmation dialogue the widget has.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to a button or other UI element on your custom interface. When the customer clicks on the button or element, the code will be executed and the chat session will be ended.
Here is an example of how to add the code to a button:
HTML
`<button onclick="liveagent.chat.end()">Exit Chat</button>`

When the customer clicks on the "Exit Chat" button, the chat session will be ended.
You can also use the liveagent.chat.end() code to trigger the exit/leave chat from within your own custom code. For example, you could use it to end the chat session if the customer clicks on a certain link on your website.
Here is an example of how to use the liveagent.chat.end() code from within your own custom code:

```
// Get the Live Agent chat object
var liveagentChat = liveagent.chat;
// Add an event listener to the "click" event on the link
document.getElementById('myLink').addEventListener('click', function() {
// End the chat session
liveagentChat.end();
});
```

When the customer clicks on the link, the liveagentChat.end() code will be executed and the chat session will be ended.

NOTE : liveagent.chat.end() code will only work if the customer is currently in a chat session

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I don't have "liveagent" available unless I miss something obvious. All I have access to is "embedded_svc". And I do not want to end the chat instantly. I want to trigger the end chat confirmation dialogue the widget has.